# How to resolve a specific matrix (undirected structured homogeneous graph) containing binary elements

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph

A friend asked me to do a program for him :

The program needed is for resolving a "puzzle game" composed by 10 torches, arranged like a 2x5 (or 5x2) matrix. The goal is to resolve the puzzle by having all torches alight, but here is the difficulty : when you change the state of a torch, adjacent torches have their state changed too (only adjacent, not the ones in diagonals).

So it is like I have a specific matrix which contain binary elements that I need to resolve by turning all elements to True (or "alight"), but elements are linked with adjacent elements like an undirected structured homogeneous graph ("mesh" graph).

Here is some picture to figure how the puzzle works :

[Exemple of initial pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIJ5J.png)

[Puzzle Mechanics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvUVf.png)

Here is where I need some help/advice/clue :

First, how can I solve this kind of puzzle in a clever way (already done it by trying all possibilities, but when I need more than 5 "step", it takes really too much time to calculate), using maths.

Then, which programming langage should I use ? Which one would fit the best to this kind of processing ? (I want to do an interface where user enter an initial pattern, then the program search the solution and give the step to resolve it by giving coords and eventualy all steps in pictures on the interface. I will surely post it on a forum for my friend and his game mates.)

I'm still searching, but have not found anything that could help me to effectively resolve that kind of puzzle yet.

Thanks a lot for any help and contribution.

PS : sorry for any bad use of english.

Answer (score -1):

You can solved this problem by using BruteForce approach.

There are only 10 torches and you just need to press each torch **exactly once**. So it will be 2^10 = 1024 combination.

For the programming language you can use: Python, C/C++, Java or C#.
Any programming language can solved this problem.

Comment: I already did it with Python, but when I need more than 5 or 6 moves it takes several minutes to calculate using BruteForce, so I wanted to know if there is any math theory / algorithme I could use to decrease the processing time for these cases.
I will try with an other langage, as Pyhton is an interpreted langage, maybe it will be enough.

Comment: I think you use incorrect BruceForce, there are only 1024 possible combination. Even if you code with Python, it should be less than 5 secs.